# How to change the child of a listtile when tapped

Tags: flutter, list, dart, mobile, state

```
searchResult = ['john','doe','smith'];
Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    width: ScreenSize.screenWidth,
                    child: Center(
                      child:searchResult.isEmpty? Text("Oops! Looks like you have no friends at the moment.") : ListView.builder(itemCount: searchResult.length,itemBuilder: (context , index){
                        return ListTile(
                          
                          
                          title: Text(searchResult[index]['username']),
                          subtitle: Text(searchResult[index]['email']),
                          
                          trailing: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              
                              
                              
                              
                            },
                            child: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline)),
                            
                        );

                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

In the above code i want to perform a function in the onTap which when tapped changes the icon of that particular list tile **Only** to a Icon(Icons.done).

I tried using the setState but couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ListTileCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListTileCustomWidget({
    required this.email,
    required this.userName,
    super.key,
  });
  final String email;
  final String userName;

  @override
  State<ListTileCustomWidget> createState() => _ListTileCustomWidgetState();
}

class _ListTileCustomWidgetState extends State<ListTileCustomWidget> {
  bool _isDone = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      trailing: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _isDone = !_isDone;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(_isDone ? Icons.done : Icons.add_circle_outline),
      ),
      title: Text(widget.email),
      subtitle: Text(widget.userName),
    );
  }
}
```

Now pass the value,

```
    Expanded( 
                          child: Container(
                            width: ScreenSize.screenWidth,
                            child: Center(
                              child:searchResult.isEmpty? Text("Oops! Looks like you have no friends at the moment.") : ListView.builder(
itemCount: searchResult.length,
itemBuilder: (context , index){
         return ListTileCustomWidget (
email: searchResult[index]['email'],
userName : searchResult[index]['username']
    );
 
                              })
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a state level variable,

```
 bool isDone = false;
```

Change the variable value on click on the button and change the value accordingly.

```
    searchResult = ['john','doe','smith']; 



Expanded( 
                  child: Container(
                    width: ScreenSize.screenWidth,
                    child: Center(
                      child:searchResult.isEmpty? Text("Oops! Looks like you have no friends at the moment.") : ListView.builder(itemCount: searchResult.length,itemBuilder: (context , index){
                        return ListTile(
                          
                          
                          title: Text(searchResult[index]['username']),
                          subtitle: Text(searchResult[index]['email']),
                          
                          trailing: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              
                              setState((){
                                  isDone = true; 

                                })
                              
                              
                            },
                            child: Icon(isDone ?  Icons.done :  Icons.add_circle_outline)),
                            
                        );

                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: The above code changes the icon of every listtile . I want it to change the icon of the tile that is clicked only.

Comment: Create a new widget class,  pass the username and email to the class. and on tap change the icon.